# OpenSSL - compile out of source

Tags: openssl

Is it possible to compile v1.0.2n of OpenSSL out of source which is desirable when building for a number of different architectures? The `Configure` perl script assumes that all paths are relative to the `build` directory rather than the `source` directory. Which leads to a bunch of unable to locate file errors.

Comment: You are supposed to be able to build out-of-tree, but I may be crossing my wires on versions. I know OpenSSL 1.1.0 builds out-of-tree because the changes for it broke some patches I have. Maybe you need to set `OPENSSL_SOURCE` for OpenSSL 1.0.2 as detailed in [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/INSTALL).

Comment: That bit at the bottom of INSTALL says you need to use symbolic links to make it work. I guess I can also just use git and reset and clean the repo.

Comment: OpenSSL's clean rule used to be screwed up. It could still be borked. It would clean too much, like the self tests. Maybe it is mucking with the symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is not really. In the documentation for OpenSSL you can find a paragraph about using symbolic links to provide the out-of-source build, but that really is a lot of trouble, especially if you're doing some sort of build-system automation.

You can look at my [CMake OpenSSL for iOS](https://github.com/palmerc/CMake_OpenSSL) project and see that I just treat OpenSSL as disposable. You can make this better by checking in OpenSSL to git and then resetting the source directory when you're done.

```
git reset --hard
git clean -f -d
```